# PDFLatex related question

Tags: pdftex

We are also using PDFLatex for generating the PDF files. My question here is, one of my customer requesting the Graphics DPI as mentioned below

For Grayscale - Maixmum DPI is 300 and Minimum DPI is 300

For Color figures - Maximum DPI is 300 and Minimum DPI is 300

For Monochrome image -Maximum DPI is 1000 and Minimum DPI is 1000

How we can achieve the above points in PDFLatex?

Thanks
Subbu

Comment: Can you use `convert -density` command of ImageMagic?

Answer (score 7):

pdfTeX does not have image manipulating facilities. Images are included as they are. If an image, e.g. `foobar.png`, has the correct resolution, e.g. color image with 300 dpi, then a plain `\includegraphics{foobar}` will do. Option `scale` can be used to change the resolution, e.g.: `\includegraphics[scale=2]{foobar}` if the color image `foobar.png` has resolution 600 dpi. Of course, the size of the image is then also increased. Therefore the images should be provided with the correct resolution/size ratio.

Usually pdfTeX recognizes the resolution data, provided in the bitmap images. If these data are missing, then the setting of `\pdfimageresolution` is used as last resort (unit is dpi = dots per inch).